# How to keep URL routing DRY

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to have the option to have a route for UserName (which can change) and one for UserId. This way the user can gain the benefit of an easy to remember URL `Users/{UserName}` along with one that will be guaranteed to never change `Users/{UserId}`

Is there any way to avoid having to write 2 routes for every route that has user as the base?

EDIT from comments

I would like to avoid handling this in the method, also. I would rather handle it in the routing.

Comment: no, b/c they are different types

Comment: on 2nd thought, you could use the same route for strings and then check if the passed param can be treated as int.

Comment: @DaveA Yah, I thought about that, but that seems kind of hacky......

Comment: it is. but if you wana restrict to one route, what option is there?

Comment: @DaveA Well, I was hoping to ferret out another option via this question :)

Comment: I hear ya. I can help you only by ruling out any option.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a request is passing in a UserId or a UserName, you need to determine if the input parameter is an int or a string.  You have two options for this:

1. Make the determination in the action method
2. Make the determination in the routing.

If you make the determination in the action method, then you can handle both of these cases in a single route. You would handle this by setting up a route as follow:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "User/{userSpecifier}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Then, in the Index action method in your Home controller, you would need to check if the input parameter is an int or a string, via code as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index(string userSpecifier)
{
    int userId = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(userSpecifier, out userId))
    {
        //It is an int, and userId contains the user Id, so process accordingly
    }
    else
    {
        //It is not an int, so treat userSpecifier as username and process accordingly
    }
    ....

    return View();
}
```

So if the string passed to the "userSpecifier" input parameter can be converted to an int, then you can assume that it is a UserId and treat it accordingly.  If it cannot be converted to an int, they you can assume that it is a UserName and react accordingly.

Of course, this solution is predicated on the assumption that UserId is an int and UserName is a string, which is how most applications would be set up.

If you want to instead want to make this determination in the routing, then you would have to set up two routes, and use [route contraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) to contrain one route to handle input parameters that are integers and a second route to handle input parameters that are strings.

Comment: If you would have read the comments between Dave A and myself, you would see that this has already been suggested and put down as a hacky. I realize that these might be the only 2 options, but would like a way to setup the routing without two baselines. Also, please do not change tags unless they are plain wrong. I tried to ignore ASP specific tags mostly in case there is another solution in another language I could mimic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would first start by asking why you would need to refer by both? If this was an Web API route (i.e. restful) you would only generally have one get method for a user API call. I'm not saying what you're doing is wrong of course! I'm just asking if having two ways of retrieving users is really required?

Comment: I have already answered the reason in my question. I want one path that is volatile (username is changeable), and one path that will never change (userid is immutable). This makes for the first option of an easy to remember path, and the second for something that is guaranteed for all time